# Access page variables in form template

Tags: forms, theming, users

I have a customised form template 'user-profile-edit.tpl.php' and i'm trying to add some custom variables so I can get a block of dynamic content (users current friends / requests etc) to display in the middle of the form.

I can use 'MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter()' to add to the form but this is not ideal as they are not form items but arbitrary markup from a custom module. I'm having to hack the form structure as follows:

```
$form['my_custom_stuff'] = array(
    '#markup' = 'some markup',
    '#description = 'some more markup',
    '#title' = 'yet more markup',
);
```

which is not nice.

Ideally i'd like to find a way to pass variables created in 'MODULE_preprocess_page()' to the 'user-profile-edit.tpl.php'. Is this possible?

Alternatively - is there a way to add custom elements to the form array without getting 'Fatal error: Unsupported operand type'?

And, no I can't change the order of the fields - the design was signed off a long time before I got involved with this project!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try $variables[] in your preprocess function!

```
 function template_preprocess_foo(&$variables) {
  $variables['foo_list'] = array(
    'list item 1',
    'list item 2',
    'list item 3',
  );
}
```

Comment: I can add stuff to the $variables array but I can only access them from the page template - I need to get them in the form template